# How to use the Diffie-Hellman parameters for generating a private and public key pairs:

Tags: key, private, public

I need to generate private and public key pairs from this information provided, my question is:

I need to put this in a file with extension .pem for creating the private and pu blic key using openssl?

```
"Diffie-Hellman-Parameters: (1024 bit)
Prime (p):
d1:93:93:25:5e:41:90:96:66:81:74:e3:5c:81:8a:
66:11:7f:79:9e:86:66:c8:05:0e:e4:36:f9:80:13:
.........
generator (g): 5 (0x5)"
```

Or how must I use this parameter given?